# Uploading files with filereference with firefox browser

Tags: apache-flex, firefox, filereference

uploading files with in Flash with  Filereference Class is not working  in FireFox . it's ok in IE , chrome ... I tried to incluse SessionId and this does'nt work for me. i guess firefox is uploading the same file Twice . is there a way to block the second unecessary Upload ?

Comment: Please explain what "Doesn't work" means.  Is the problem on the server, or the client?  Do you get a runtime error?  If so, what is the error?  you may consider sharing some code.

Comment: I Think that the request is not reaching the server (i put some breakpoints in servlet filtres that should be entered for every http request ) . the error  : #2038 IO error . thx for your reply

Comment: I already noticed some duplicate requests when using https...

Comment: I m also using https under ssl , is it a bug in fileReference ?

Comment: In fact I installed FireFox Extension To list the http traffic to the server . When this code is executed this._fileReference.upload(urlRequest);  nothing is wired to the server . I suppose that it's someThing in flashRuntime Blocking the Request !!!

Comment: @SamiJmii Did you find a solution to this issue? I am also facing the same issue. The request is not reaching the server.

Comment: Not Yet , we are not using fireFox in production . please keep me in touch .